# I want to delete all the duplicates row in a MySQL database but it freezes

Tags: mysql, duplicates

whenever I try a deleting operation on my phpmyAdmin MySQL database it freezes saying 'Error 504' once I run the command.

The operation is like the following:

```
DELETE t1 FROM downloads t1
        INNER JOIN
    downloads t2
WHERE
    t1.ID < t2.ID AND t2.download = t2.download AND t2.place = t2.place AND t2.IP = t2.IP AND t2.data = t2.data
```

I have a table with dozens thousands entries and I just want to keep those with the highest ID and removing the otherd having lowest ID+same place+same IP+same data.

Comment: It's often quicker to construct a new table with just the data you want to retain.

Comment: the condition `t2.download = t2.download AND t2.place = t2.place AND t2.IP = t2.IP AND t2.data = t2.data` is, obviously, always true (unless you have `NULL` values)

Comment: and then copy the database from the old to the new, delete the old and rename the new table? @Strawberry maybe that works on the low traffic application but not on a high traffic one the new table might mis inserted/updated/deleted data before the deleting the old table and renaming happens.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Good point - needs to be some kind of transaction.

Comment: i doubt that will work? @Strawberry DDL statements  (like `CREATE TABLE`) in MySQL will implict commit a transaction.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I didn't necessarily mean an SQL transaction ;-)

Comment: Not sure if you should go that way and handle SQL data integrity within a application "transaction" @Strawberry those are NoSQL sins..

Comment: @RaymondNijland In this instance, the choice appears to be between an imperfectsolution and and one that won't work at all. :-(

Comment: True.. @Strawberry a better workaround might be adding partitions on a delete column and truncate the `deleted = 1` partition now i think off it.. But then you need to update a large part of the table which is also slow if you don't optimize it correctly. meaning having a large covering index.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I have changed with t1.download = t2.download AND t1.place = t2.place AND t1.IP = t2.IP AND t1.data = t2.data and it freezes giving error 504 after a minute anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - your joining alias is not right you are trying `t2.download = t2.download` and so on which is wrong

```
DELETE t1
FROM downloads t1
INNER JOIN downloads t2
WHERE t1.ID < t2.ID
  AND t1.download = t2.download
  AND t1.place = t2.place
  AND t1.IP = t2.IP
  AND t1.data = t2.data
```

Comment: just tried but it's the same: loading for circa 50 seconds then a red box appear in which it's written "Error in processing request Error code: 504 It seems that the connection to server has been lost"

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, if you can take the system off-line for a couple of minutes, then I'd do this:

```
-- After making a backup of downloads...

CREATE TABLE new_downloads AS
SELECT a.* 
  FROM downloads a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(id) id
         FROM downloads 
        GROUP 
           BY download
            , place
            , IP
            , data 
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id;

ALTER TABLE new_downloads ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
-- add any other indexes as required

DROP TABLE downloads;

ALTER TABLE new_downloads RENAME TO downloads;
```